# R Generate Multiple Plots for a single pdf

Tags: r, plot

I have a list of about 100 different groups;

```
categories <- c('cat1','cat2','cat3',....)
```

I would like to write a loop that goes and grabs only the data for 1 category at a time, and generate a plot (x,y); for example...

```
for (i in 1:length(categories){
category_data <- data[which(data$category==categories[i]),]
plot(category_data$y,category_data$x)}
### however, I would like to save EACH plot to a single PDF that I can scroll through to quickly visualize everything at once
```

How can I generate a single PDF with 100 different plots?

Comment: You could easily do this with Rmarkdown and the `knitr` package.

Comment: You want a different plot on each page of the PDF? So you'd end up with a 100 page PDF?

Comment: good point @CephBirk. Maybe it would be better to do like 4 plots per page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the OP wanting 4 plots per PDF page, I would recommend:

```
pdf('plots.pdf')
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for (i in 1:length(categories){
    category_data <- data[which(data$category==categories[i]),]
    plot(category_data$y,category_data$x)}
dev.off()
```

If the OP decides to plot a different number of graphs per page, the `mfrow` parameter can be changed. Currently it is set for 2 rows x 2 columns = 4 plots per page.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a multiple page pdf by using the pdf function (or png, jpeg, etc), generating all of the files that you want to and then closing the file with dev.off

```
pdf(file = "output.pdf")

for (i in 1:length(categories){
   category_data <- data[which(data$category==categories[i]),]
   plot(category_data$y,category_data$x)}

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used R for much of the graphing in my college statistics and calculus classes. The best way I found to incorporating multiple plots into a single PDF was to apply the principle of [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

R was great at generating the plots (I favored the png format), but LaTeX rocked for generating PDFs. My simplified workflow looked something like this:

1. Generate the plots in a known folder, with sequentially generated names (`graph_01.png`, etc).
2. Open a template file I kept around to avoid having to recreate the boilerplate code.
3. Use a shell script to generate [markup](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Inserting_Images) needed to insert the image.
4. Do any manual cleanup, add captions, etc.
5. Generate the pdf using `pdflatex`

It was very easy, and almost completely automated.